# Web.config transformation with dot in filename (Web.Release.config and Web.Release.Azure.config), last one not used

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to have two configuration - Release and Release.Azure, second one is created by Configuration Manager, then i use 'Add web.config transformation' and have a 'Web.Release.Azure.config' as result (with some transformation inside).

While publishing to azure using Release.Azure configuration, transformation from file 'Web.Release.config' is applied, not from 'Web.Release.Azure.config'. I'm tested it with local filesystem publish and got same result.

How to get 'Web.Release.Azure.config' works? VS 2012 with Update 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft [declared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that "The build configuration that a transform is for is indicated by a string in the file name. For example, a transform file for the Debug build configuration is named Web.Debug.config." But it looks like it used not full string compare.

My problem is solved by naming configuration without dot: ReleaseAzure with associated with Web.ReleaseAzure.config